# ¿Como solucionar el error appCompatActivity al querer agregar la funcion de regresar atras desde toolbar en un fragment?

Tags: java, android-studio

en esta ocasión vengo con un error que me salio ya que quiero agregar la función de retroceder hacia atrás desde fragment, ya que tengo los títulos en toolbar solo me falta el retroceso y me lleve al menú principal.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Servicios");
    appCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_volcan_popocatepetl, container, false);


}
```

** Captura de error**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el contexto, si te encuentras dentro de un Fragment esto es incorrecto:

```
 appCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

debes realizar esto obteniendo el contexto de la Activity que contiene el Fragmento.

```
 ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Que tal amigo  Jorgesys así ya tenia antes tal como me comentas ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); pero el problema era que como en el menú principal tengo una vavigation drawer y  tengo el icono de hamburguesa y se me cambia todo al icono de de retroceso.